# What is a good stategy to understand function return function in ML?

Tags: sml, ml

```
val g1 = fn x => fn y => fn z => (x y) :: z;
val g1 = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'b list
```

This is the code and output. I have no idea why the output is like this.

I understand `'b list -> 'b list` since `z` is obviously a list so `(x y) :: z` is list as well.

However, I do not understand why `fn x => fn y` is `('a -> 'b) -> 'a`.

I have no idea why it is `('a -> 'b) -> 'a`.

Please give me a good strategy to understand this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing there that has type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a`.

`->` associates to the right, so

```
('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'b list
```

is

```
('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> ('b list -> 'b list))
```

and so does the definition;

```
fn x => fn y => fn z => (x y) :: z
```

is

```
fn x => (fn y => (fn z => (x y) :: z))
```

That is,

- `x` is `'a -> 'b`
- `y` is `'a`
- `z` is `'b list`
- the result is `'b list`

Perhaps it gets clearer if you uncurry the function

```
fun g2(x, y, z) = (x y) :: z
```

which has type

```
(('a -> 'b) * 'a * 'b list) -> 'b list
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering! Just a final small question. if x is `'a -> 'b` and y is `'a`, (x y) becomes `'b`. Am I correct?

Comment: @MarsLee Correct.

Comment: Thank you!! This really helps!